# RegEx for capturing a token from an HTML element

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

So I'm trying to get a value from a  object in html. I've found out how to get the value, but there's extra stuff being added to it that I don't want.

I've tried using .split() and groups but none of those have done anything.

```py
html = r.text
checkouttoken = re.search('DF_CHECKOUT_TOKEN = (.*?);', html, re.S)

print(checkouttoken.group(0))
```

Expected:

```
27f37949bb8a76ede81508c8c1b750c8
```

Actual:

```
< iframe srcdoc="&lt;script&gt;!function(){var e=function(e){var t={exports:{}};return e.call(t.exports,t,t.exports),t.exports},r=function(){fun
DF_CHECKOUT_TOKEN = "27f37949bb8a76ede81508c8c1b750c8";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `group(1)`. `group(0)` is all of the matched text, `group(1)` is the first group that you captured.

Also, if you don't want the quotations in the result, you will need to add the quotations to the regex, outside of the capture group: `'DF_CHECKOUT_TOKEN = "(.*?)";'`

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I was looking for. I'm looking to isolate the checkout token and leave the excess bits behind.

Comment: Got it myself, I split the string. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The expression we might want here can be as simple as:

```
DF_CHECKOUT_TOKEN = \"(.+?)\"
```

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"DF_CHECKOUT_TOKEN = \"(.+?)\""

test_str = "< iframe srcdoc=\"<script>!function(){var e=function(e){var t={exports:{}};return e.call(t.exports,t,t.exports),t.exports},r=function(){fun DF_CHECKOUT_TOKEN = \"27f37949bb8a76ede81508c8c1b750c8\";"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WACn5/1)